# Cannot ssh directly to a machine, but can ssh through another machine

Tags: networking, ssh

I cannot ssh to machine A, it says `No route to host`.

I can ssh to machine B and once logged in there I can ssh to machine A.

How is this possible?

(My machine and machine A run Ubuntu, machine B runs Fedora, machines A and B are desktops, my machine is a laptop on WiFi).

Output of `route`

My machine:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         buffalo.setup   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.11.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

Machine A

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.10.145.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.145.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

Machine B:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.10.145.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p5p1
10.10.145.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p5p1
```

Comment: How is the network setup ?

Comment: @Lawrence I'm sorry I don't know what the network setup is. All the IPs are static though. What kind of n/w will allow such a thing to happen?

Comment: I've had similar issues when I had 2 WiFi APs, and was trying to access one machine that was connected to one AP when I was connected to the other AP.

Comment: what’s the output of `route` on both A and B? are you certian that the network connection is functioning on machine A?

Comment: @FrankThomas updated details in the question. Yes, I can surely ssh into A from B.

Comment: You may be in another subnet. What is `buffalo.setup` ? Use `route -n` not to resolve hostnames. If that's the case, the firewall on machine B (`firewalld` on Fedora) is blocking the incoming connection from another subnet.

Comment: is your wifi access point in AP/Bridge mode, or Router mode? do you have a setting with a name like 'client isolation' or 'AP isolation' enabled on the wifi device? otherwise it looks like you have 2 or three differant IP networks, and inconsistent connectivity between them.